# How to track container on host machine

Tags: linux, docker

If I wanted to know how long a given container ran on a given host machine. Is there a way to figure this out or any tools to measure this metric?

Answer (score 2):

See next:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
302f9a721dff        ubuntu:16.04        "/bin/bash"         7 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds                            nervous_lovelace
```

`CREATED`: means when the container created

`STATUS`: means how long the container has run since last start

Answer (score 2):

[docker inspect](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/inspect/) can return information about the state of the container.

```
docker inspect  --format='{{json .State}}' container_id
```

To get the exact time when the container was started and eventually exited

```
docker inspect  --format='Started: {{.State.StartedAt}} - Finished: {{.State.FinishedAt}}' container_id
```

Putting the pieces together the following will print the uptime of a running or stopped container in `hours:minutes:seconds`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

running=`docker inspect  --format='{{.State.Running}}' ${1}`

if [ "${running}" == "true" ]; then
    end=$(date -d 'now' +%s)
else 
    finishedAt=`docker inspect --format='{{.State.FinishedAt}}' ${1}`
    end=$(date -d "${finishedAt}" +%s)
fi

startedAt=`docker inspect --format='{{.State.StartedAt}}' ${1}`
start=$(date -d "${startedAt}" +%s)
secs=$(( (end - start) ))

printf 'Uptime: %dh:%dm:%ds\n' $(($secs/3600)) $(($secs%3600/60)) $(($secs%60))
```

Run with container id.